# Trash folder in /tmp?

Tags: 22.04, xubuntu, filesystem

I just installed Xubuntu 22.04 on a new machine. My old machine running 18.04 died.
On both machines, I have /tmp setup as a ram drive.

On 18.04, /tmp had a trash folder (I think it was .Trash-1000). In Thunar, if I pressed Delete on a file, it went into trash. Shift-Delete was a permanent delete.

On 22.04, there is no trash option in /tmp. If I press Delete, it says the file will be permanently deleted.

Any idea how to add the trash option back into /tmp ?

Comment: Hi, can you check "~/.config/Thunar/accels.scm" file for string `(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/Thunar/trash" "<Primary>Delete")` ?

Comment: "On 18.04, /tmp had a trash folder"  that seems a security violation to me and I really doubt /tmp/ had a trash. 1st of /tmp is set to 777 with sticky bit so -anyone- could access those files. Plus  /tmp is empties on reboot making it impossible to restore files.  Both are bad. `~/.local/share/Trash/` has been the location for trash for a long long time. IF you had a trash in /tmp/ you changed it to that.

Comment: @Yousha Aleayoub I do not see "(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/Thunar/trash" "<Primary>Delete")". Should I add it? If so will Thunar apply it immediately, or do I need to logout/reboot?